# Flask-SocketIO in public cloud: requests to upgrade to websocket fail in some cases

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am building sample web-based calculator where all clients must immediately see updates other clients make.
Locally it works beautiful, however when deployed to AWS EC2 client requests to upgrade to websocket fail in some cases both in Chrome(77.x) and Firefox(60.x). As I understand it, the server blocks everything trying to upgrade it and then client disconnects after timeout.

**requirements.txt:**

```
alembic==1.1.0
Click==7.0
dnspython==1.16.0
eventlet==0.25.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SocketIO==4.2.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
greenlet==0.4.15
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
monotonic==1.5
psycopg2==2.8.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-dotenv==0.10.3
python-editor==1.0.4
python-engineio==3.9.3
python-socketio==4.3.1
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.7
Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

**client = socket.io 2.2.0**

**Server code:**

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
#...other imports...
socketio = SocketIO(application, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('json')
    def get_new_equation_item(someJson):
        try:
            send(someJson, json=True, broadcast=True, include_self=False)

            #Adding new equation to the database
            equation_item = Calculation(body=someJson["emitItem"])
            db.session.add(equation_item)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            error = "Incorrect data from the client"
            flash(error, 'error')
            return render_template('calc_index.html')

#...other code...
socketio.run(application, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Client logs:** you can check at http://ec2-54-146-7-208.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000

**Server logs:**

```
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:15:33] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJSFH&sid=0784c7202fc64d7fbb6d130bf574c0e5 HTTP/1.1" 400 186 60.001675
89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
client connected: 9
89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:15:34] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJh6W HTTP/1.1" 200 349 0.001331
(25584) accepted ('24.118.131.176', 39652)
89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337: Received request to upgrade to websocket
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:15:34] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJh8g&sid=89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337 HTTP/1.1" 200 183 0.113250
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 566, in handle_one_response
    result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 46, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 534, in handle_request
    return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 366, in handle_request
    environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 106, in handle_get_request
    start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 146, in _upgrade_websocket
    return ws(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/async_drivers/eventlet.py", line 20, in __call__
    return super(WebSocketWSGI, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 130, in __call__
    self.handler(ws)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 171, in _websocket_handler
    pkt = ws.wait()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 788, in wait
    for i in self.iterator:
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 643, in _iter_frames
    message = self._recv_frame(message=fragmented_message)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 669, in _recv_frame
    header = recv(2)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 578, in _get_bytes
    d = self.socket.recv(numbytes - len(data))
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 366, in recv
    return self._recv_loop(self.fd.recv, b'', bufsize, flags)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 360, in _recv_loop
    self._read_trampoline()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 331, in _read_trampoline
    timeout_exc=socket_timeout('timed out'))
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 210, in _trampoline
    mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 159, in trampoline
    return hub.switch()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venvs/sezzle-calc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 298, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
socket.timeout: timed out

24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:16:34] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337 HTTP/1.1" 500 0 60.056104
Client disconnected: 9
89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337: Client is gone, closing socket
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:16:34] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJhBM&sid=89b7a287731d4232b05c5efb59439337 HTTP/1.1" 400 186 60.001529
2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
client connected: 9
2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:16:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJw3v HTTP/1.1" 200 349 0.001351
(25584) accepted ('24.118.131.176', 39654)
2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f: Received request to upgrade to websocket
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:16:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrAJw5e&sid=2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f HTTP/1.1" 200 183 0.106838
^Cwsgi exiting
2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f: Failed websocket upgrade, expected UPGRADE packet, received None instead.
24.118.131.176 - - [19/Sep/2019 16:16:49] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=2736a74a53514ed18127c17d6b5ed51f HTTP/1.1" 200 0 13.647335
```

Thanks. Pls let me know if additional info is needed

Comment: This is probably due to an operation that you do on your server that is blocking eventlet or gevent (you have both installed, you should pick one and uninstall the other). Are you doing any CPU intensive work that might block for a long time?

Comment: Miguel, thanks for reply! I actually did not have gevent installed, listed old libs.
On client emit I only write new equation string to database - added this method to the server code in initial post. Cannot take longer than 60 secs...

Comment: 60 seconds is an eternity for eventlet or other async frameworks. The CPU needs to be released often so that other concurrent tasks get to run.

Comment: I should clarify that I cannot say if you are doing a CPU intensive activity from the snippet of code you posted. This is just something I suspect is happening based on the error that you get.